# Index created successfully, but won't reindex new data

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, groovy, janusgraph, reindex

I'm totally bamboozled, since this code was working previously.

I'm trying to create a Mixed Edge index on an edge property in my graph (`trxn_dt_int`).

It shows, from the output of `mgmt.printSchema()`, that it was created successfully (see, Status: **Enabled**, I've highlighted the relevant rows).

`mgmt.printSchema()` output:

```
==>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertex Label Name              | Partitioned | Static                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity                         | false       | false                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edge Label Name                | Directed    | Unidirected | Multiplicity                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
transacts_with                 | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Property Key Name              | Cardinality | Data Type                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
benef_nm                       | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
orig_nm                        | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
trxn_dt_int                    | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Float                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertex Index Name              | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
***************************************************************************************************

Edge Index (VCI) Name          | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
byDate                         | Mixed       | false     | search         | trxn_dt_int:   ENABLED|

***************************************************************************************************
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Relation Index                 | Type        | Direction | Sort Key       | Order    |     Status |
```

Here's my groovy script to create the index:

```
graph.tx().rollback() 
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.printSchema()

// get index count
index_count = mgmt.getGraphIndexes(Edge.class).size()

if (index_count==0) {

    // create edge schema for graph (only for properties to be indexed)
    if (!mgmt.getEdgeLabel('transacts_with') & !mgmt.getPropertyKey('trxn_dt_int')) {
        transacts_with = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('transacts_with').make()
        trxn_dt = mgmt.makePropertyKey('trxn_dt_int').dataType(Float.class).make()
        mgmt.addProperties(transacts_with, trxn_dt)
    }
    mgmt.commit()

    mgmt = graph.openManagement()
    if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("byDate")) {
        trxn_dt = mgmt.getPropertyKey('trxn_dt_int')

        mgmt.buildIndex('byDate', Edge.class).addKey(trxn_dt).buildMixedIndex('search')

        mgmt.commit()

        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'byDate').call()

        mgmt = graph.openManagement()
        mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byDate"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
        mgmt.commit()
    }
}
```

When I query the elasticsearch server, it shows it's there:

```
curl --silent 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices' | cut -d\  -f3
> janusgraph_bydate
```

When I query for the number of documents, it returns 0.

```
curl --silent 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/janusgraph_bydate/_count?q=*'
> {"count":0,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}
```

My question is, why aren't any documents being added?

I initially thought I had to reindex, but when I tried, it still didn't work. No errors at all.

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex('byDate')
mgmt.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
mgmt.commit()
```

Setup:

- Janusgraph 0.5.1
- Elasticsearch 6.0.1

Comment: "this code was working previously" - what has changed?  can you bisect
the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing; it wasn't updating the index with new data because my machine lacked sufficient memory, but also didn't offer warnings to suggest this. After freeing up memory elsewhere it now works again.